# Validation of parameters in a chain of services

Tags: design, architecture

We have a chain of service A -> B -> C -> D.
A defines format of certain parameters say ParamA
B defines format of certain parameters say ParamB

D is the one which actually uses these parameters and C pass them to D. The role of C is to get data from D and do bit of business logic on top of that and return that to B and B return that to A.

is it a good idea that C validates the parameters ParamA and ParamB or C should not worry about Parameters and let D decide because if format (one type of validation) changes C need to be updated. What are your suggestions?

Comment: Validating in one place is best.

Answer (score 3):

The decisive question you must ask yourself: **Where will the parameters actually come from in practice?**

If you know that all these methods are ultimately just for clearer understanding for the maintainer, and B, C and D are only ever called from A, then it makes no sense to verify parameters in multiple places. An obvious place to do it is A, as soon after receiving them as possible.

But of course software engineering thrives on reuse, so if B, C, or D were to be reused one day so that other parts of the system call them directly, this no longer holds. This is why clearly documenting what the pre- and post-conditions on your methods are is so important.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to provide an answer by using a rule for argument validation in methods. When deciding about when the arguments of methods need to be validated, the general rule of thumb is:

- Validate only the parameters of public methods in public classes

The exceptions to this rule are:

(the first three go if you want to be more defensive about arguments validity)

- protected methods of public classes
- public methods of internal classes
- protected methods of internal classes
- if the validity check would be expensive or impractical and the validity check is performed implicitly in the process of doing the computation

Applied to your example, I would suggest the responsibility of each validation of parameters be only in one place. Let me elaborate. The sanity check of the parameters can be done on the source side. Let's say that ParamA should be a positive number. A can easily check whether somebody put 0 or -5 as a value in ParamA. However, the semantic validation usually can be performed only on the destination side, which in this case means D.

You can, of course, do all validations in D, should you decide later on that somebody else other than A or B can use D. Either way is OK. I would only advise that you decouple the validation logic from A, B, or D by putting the validation logic in separate classes, which could be associated to A, B, or D. That way, you can easily move validations say from A to D, should you decide to do so.

In either case, I do not see a reason why C should check for validity of arguments passed to D. C is clearly just a proxy here and the only thing C should validate is the data it gets from D in order to perform whatever computation it does.